# How to make rete.js dock menu vertical?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rete

I am new to rete.js and I wanted to display the dock menu from which you can drag and drop nodes in a vertcial way rather than in the default horizantal way. Is there any ways to do this ?

from the documentation, i was expecting the following to be possible

```
dock.addPreset(DockPresets.classic.setup({ area, size: 100, scale: 0.6, orientation: vertical }));
```

but from the documentation on dock menu, there doesn't seem to be more options than just the area, size and scale of the dock.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to Rete.JS too, and it seems to me that you're right. There is no such option for now in the latest version of the rete-dock-plugin (2.0.1).

You could still use CSS to override the default behavior (with a chance that your custom style breaks on the next update).

```
.dock {
   position:absolute;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   height: 100%;
   width: 200px; }
```

[Check it out on CodePen:](https://codepen.io/kisaure/pen/YzMVRQr)